# How to remove the Jqgrid unwanted icons additionally displayed

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqgrid with sort icons(ui-icon-triangle-1-s & ui-icon-triangle-1-n) at the column headers which is fine, additionally the unwanted icons(ui-icon-triangle-1-ne & ui-icon-triangle-1-sw) are displaying along with my sort icon. I tried removing this from the column header using,

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-icon-triangle-1-ne .ui-icon-triangle-1-sw
{
display: none;
// visibility: hidden;
}
```

but it doesn't worked.

UPDATED: jQuery jqgrid v4.4.4 from NuGet Package manager in visual studio.
[image]
 Please help me to achieve this. Thanks.

Note: Similarly, in close icon of custom validation popup "ui-icon-key" is additionally displayed.

Comment: Please include more details about what you do (see my comment to other your last questions). It would be very helpful to include pictures additionally, which demonstrates the problem, which you try to solve.

Comment: @Oleg: Thanks for your feedback. I'm sure I will definitely mention version in my every question. Please find the UPDATED question for version and picture. Thanks

Comment: The problem, which one can see on the pictures should not exist even in case of usage retro versions of jqGrid. I suppose that you added some unneeded CSS rules, which are origin of your problem or you have some conflictes between jQuery UI and other CSS framework, which you included. **You should provide the demo, which reproduces the problem.** It could be that you incorrectly increased the `height` and `width` of jQuery UI icons, which are not scaleable and **must** have original fixed size. It's one of the reasons, why I implemented support of Font Awesome in free jqGrid.